# Remove all html iframes except for youtube embed

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I want to remove all html iframes but I want to keep Youtube embeds with HTMLpurifier. I've looked around for answers but haven't gotten this problem solved.

The code I've written so far

```
<?php

include "htmlpurifier-config.php";
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', array());
$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', 'a,script,iframe');
$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenAttributes', 'height,width');
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'); //allow YouTube and Vimeo
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$text = $purifier->purify($document);

?>
```

I think the issue I have is that having this line: `$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', 'a,script,iframe');` will remove all iframe and script tags including Youtube embeds. Is there a way to remove all iframe and script except for Youtube embeds?

Please help, thank you :)

Comment: This is more of a heads-up than an answer, hence commenting: I'd recommend just leaving `HTML.ForbiddenElements` away. `HTML.Trusted` already corresponds to a more permissive whitelist than the one HTML Purifier has by default. See if that helps you (or sends you in the right investigative direction, either way)? :)

Comment: i'm looking into it. Thank you for the guidance :)